# Getting segmentation fault strcpy

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcpy

```
struct Object * newObj(char * nome, int idade, float altura) {
    struct Object *obj = (struct Object *) malloc(sizeof(struct Object));
    strcpy(obj->nome, nome); // This is the line
    obj->idade = idade;
    obj->altura = altura;
    return obj;
}
```

This is my code, I don't know why I'm getting segmentation fault in strcpy.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to alloc memory for `obj->nome`, `obj->nome = malloc(...)`

Comment: Please remove all casts where you don't know **exactly** what you are doing and can explain why the cast is **neccessary** for correct working. Never muzzle the compiler, instead ask it to speak up: Use `-Wall -Wextra`, and handle all warnings appropriately.

Comment: Is `obj->nome` a pointer or an array?

Comment: @pNre That was the error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `struct Object` type, the `nome` member is declared as a pointer and you also need to allocate memory for the array. Without allocating memory `obj->nome` has an inderminate value.

Comment: This was the error! Thanks a lot!