# strcpy after strtok segmentfault in C

Tags: c, strtok, strcpy

```
char test[10]="ab cd";
char* save=NULL;

save = strtok(test," ");
printf("%s\n",save);
```

result : ab

First, above code works very well.

Next, I tryed to excute this code. but, segmentfault occurs.

```
char test[10]="ab cd";
char* save=NULL;
char* cpy=NULL;

save = strtok(test," ");
strcpy(cpy,save);
printf("%s\n",cpy);
```

I know strtok() returns read-only *char type. 
but, i guess, 'save' is used only copied object.

it is not change. why strcpy() makes segmentfault error by get 'save' as parameter?

Comment: What do you think `cpy` points at to make it deserving of the target of a `strcpy` ? one of countless related duplicates [can be seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885961/getting-segmentation-fault-strcpy).

Comment: You cannot copy a string to a `NULL` pointer, as in `char* cpy=NULL; ... strcpy(cpy,save);`. Segfault.

Comment: Predictable..................:(

Comment: strcpy doesn't allocate memory for you.  you need to have the destination of strcpy be already allocated memory locations.

Comment: when calling `strtok()`, Always check (!=NULL) the returned value before using that returned value for anything.

Comment: suggest using `strdup()` rather than `strcpy()`.    Strongly suggest reading/understanding the man pages for the system functions that you call.  The posted code clearly shows that certain details (described in the man pages) were not understood

Answer (score 1):

`cpy` is explicitly NULL when you copy into the location it's pointing to. That's guaranteed to give you a memory write error of some kind.

I suggest you initialize `cpy` to point to some memory that's actually available, e.g.:

```
char temp[100];
char test[10]="ab cd";
char* save=NULL;
char* cpy=temp; // Set cpy to point to temp buffer

save = strtok(test," ");
strcpy(cpy,save);
printf("%s\n",cpy);
```

It's not `strtok()` that's causing the problem, it's the `strcpy()` into address 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your `char *cpy` is not referencing any allocated memory. (You initialized it to `NULL`. So when you call `strcpy(cpy,save)`, you are writing to a NULL-pointer.

You might want to allocate memory first:

```
cpy = malloc(strlen(save)+1);
strcyp(cpy,save);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `strcpy` case you have to first allocate memory for "cpy" so that "save" can be copied to "cpy". Here "save" is working fine because `strtok` only return pointer on success...That's why you don't need to allocate memory for "save".And you are passing an address by save so it's fine..So overall first allocate memory for "cpy" so that `strcpy` can copy "save" into "cpy".

Answer (score 0):

Use [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup)

```
save = strtok(test," ");
cpy = strdup(save);
printf("%s\n",cpy);
free(cpy);
```

Don't forget to free the memory when you're done with it.

Also [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020380/strcpy-vs-strdup)

Answer (score 0):

As provided earlier, strcpy() like most string routines will segfault if passed a NULL argument. This applies to both the src and dest args (at least in older versions of glibc), which makes it impossible to do simple things like:

```
strcpy(dest, strtok(NULL, “ “));
strcpy(dest, getenv(“NOTHNG”);
```

Either strtok() or getenv() could return a NULl, which is passed to strcpy() causing a segfault. I didn’t want to put a lot of NULL checking into my code, like:

```
if (getenv(“NOTHING”) != NULL)
    *dest = ‘\0’;
else
    strcpy(dest, getenv(“NOTHING”));
```

So, I created a strcpy_w() wrapper that treats a NULL src argument the same as if *src is ‘\0’. I did the same for other string functions, also checking for buffer overflows. Then, I just had to add the following to always use the wrapper:

```
#define strcpy(x, y) strcpy_w(x, y)
```

Or I could call strcpy_w(dest, getenv(“NOTHING”)) instead.